# Spin a div but make its content not go upside down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make a div spin, aswell as its content, but make the content not go upside-down while rotating ?
What I mean is that the div-childs would follow the rotation of the mother-div spinning, but while remaining in the same direction (top on top, bottom on bottom).

My english isn't goog enough to articulate properly what I want to do, so here is an exemple :

```css
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.spin:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spin">
  <div id="div1">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div2">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div3">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div4">hello
  </div>
</div>
```

In the exemple above, the child divs are following the rotation and the spin.
I would like them not to "spin upside-down" and just follow the rotation.

I've seen these type of animation in several websites but I can't recall where exactly.
Is there a way to do this in css/js/jquery/php... ?

Comment: you'd have to rotate the children in sync with the parent, in the opposite direction. e.g. if the parent's gone 37 degrees clockwise, the children will have gone 37 degrees counterclockwise, and be in the same orientation they had before the parent start spinning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply the same animation to the four children, but in reverse. That way, the rotation of the children counteract the rotation of the parent and the children remain upright.

For clarity, I've used [`animation-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) to reverse the animation:

```
animation-direction: reverse;
```

But you could include the direction in your [`animation` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Syntax), like:

```
animation: spin 10s reverse infinite linear;
```

---

Here's an example:

```css
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}
.spin div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#div4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.spin:hover,
.spin:hover div {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spin">
  <div id="div1">hello</div>
  <div id="div2">hello</div>
  <div id="div3">hello</div>
  <div id="div4">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is indeed the effect I was trying to get, it looks to be very clean. In my code it is going to be way more complex with an ease-out transition in the animation but I believe it can works aswell if I follow the same path you did. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Following @showdev answer, if you want the borders around the inner divs to follow the spin of the outer block and only make the text inside to stay "fixed" in position - you can use a bit of jQuery for that:

```
    $('.spin div').each(function() {
        $(this).contents().wrap('<span></span>');
    });
```

I also added a bit of css, you can check inside the snippet:

```js
$('.spin div').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().wrap('<span></span>');
});
```

```css
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}
.spin div {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.spin div span {
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  animation-direction:reverse;
  display: inline-block;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#div4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.spin:hover, .spin:hover span {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spin">
  <div id="div1">hello</div>
  <div id="div2">hello</div>
  <div id="div3">hello</div>
  <div id="div4">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this actually more advanced than what I was trying to achieve, I hadn't thought of it that way. Since I didn't want to deal with this problem I chose to go with circles borders so they don't overflow for my design, but this would have worked too :)

Answer (score 1):

I understood you also wanted each of 4 elements to stay in the area of their corners. This might need some extra animation to have them run around the parent edges.

Below the idea of what i understood:

```css
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}
.spin div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  animation: spin1 10s infinite linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#div2 {
  animation: spin2 10s infinite linear;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#div3 {
  animation: spin3 10s infinite linear;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#div4 {
  animation: spin4 10s infinite linear;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.spin:hover,
.spin:hover div {
  animation-play-state: paused!important;/* or used id and several selectors to avoid the important and overide div#div1 {...}*/
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 0
  }
  50% {
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px
  }
  75% {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    right: 150px
  }
  50% {
    right: 150px;
    top: 150px
  }
  75% {
    top: 150px;
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px
  }
  50% {
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 150px
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 150px
  }
  50% {
    right: 150px;
    bottom: 150px
  }
  75% {
    right: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spin">
  <div id="div1">top left</div>
  <div id="div2">top right</div>
  <div id="div3">bottom left</div>
  <div id="div4">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to each numbered div:

```
counterspin 10s infinite linear;
```

and then this keyframes animation

```
@keyframes counterspin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  position:relative;
  
}
.spin div {
  margin:10px;
  animation: spin 10s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.spin:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.spin:hover div {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spin">
  <div id="div1">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div2">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div3">hello
  </div>
  <div id="div4">hello
  </div>
</div>
```

you may try this

```
.spin {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  position:relative;

}
.spin div {
  margin:10px;
  animation: spin 10s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;

}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.spin:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.spin:hover div {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
```

}